# Cloning a local git repo created with --mirror

Tags: git

I have created a local mirror from a repository a while back, lets call it `oldrepo`. 
This was originally a private repo in Bitbucket. Now, I'd like to see the code in the repo, so what I tried first was to go into the folder that contains `oldrepo` and did:

`git clone oldrepo newrepo`

This gives me `fatal: repository 'oldrepo' does not exist`

Then I tried

`git clone "C:\full\path to\oldrepo" newrepo`

This gives me

```
fatal: 'C:\full\path to\oldrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

From what I read in the docs and other answers on SO, this should be the way to go. Clearly I'm missing something

Comment: I've tested the same on a mac and there everything works as it should

Comment: Does the stuff in the directory `oldrepo` resemble a repository? Is `git fsck` happy with it?

Comment: Is `oldrepo` corrupted?

Comment: It does look like a repo to me, and like I commented, running the same on a mac works without problems